# a option is selected without selected text in the option

Tags: html, select

When option is selected by default, without 'selected' text in it. How is it possible?.

I actually need a different option but I am not able to choose anything.

Comment: Are you using angular ?

Comment: post some code then only can help

Comment: it is a pure html <select> <option></option></select> . one of the value is selected by default, there is no 'selected'.

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan by default the first option is selected if there is no option with "selected" attribute. And yes it will not have "selected" attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/959/

Comment: it's not the first option.

Answer (score 0):

// set by default selected value using "selected" property of option

```
<select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel" selected>Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

// if you don't specify form select default option is first one "Volvo"

Default first one option is selected without "selected" property set beacuse that default behavior is that

Comment: my problem is  Opel is selected by default without 'selected'

Comment: Opel is first option ?? of list of options

Answer (score 0):

If no "selected" attribute is provide, the first `option` in the select list will be selected by default. It will work this way in all browsers. Using an `option` ***with no text or value*** gives the appearance that nothing is selected:

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option><!-- this will be selected by default, but the value will be empty string-->
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: actually i have one selected option. while loading it appears first and then different option appears( no 'selected' in this option)

Comment: So the select list is changing? If this is the case, you will need to revise the question with the JavaScript that is being used.